# Printing specific lines in Unix

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

Write a script named print_lines.sh that uses head and tail together to print out a specific set of lines from a file.  The script should take three arguments: the line number to start at, the line number to stop at, and the file to use.  Here's an example run:

```
 `[user@localhost ~]$ print_lines.sh 7 10 /etc/passwd
  shutdown:x:6:0:shutdown:/sbin:/sbin/shutdown
  halt:x:7:0:halt:/sbin:/sbin/halt
  mail:x:8:12:mail:/var/spool/mail:/sbin/nologin
  operator:x:11:0:operator:/root:/sbin/nologin
  [user@localhost ~]$`
```

In this example, the script prints line 7 through 10 (inclusive) of the /etc/passwd file.  Your script must do error checking.  Specifically, you need to check all the following things:

1. You get the right number of arguments (3).
2. The file specified exists and is a normal file.
3. The first line number specified is less than or equal to the last line number specified.
4. The actual number of lines in the file is greater than the last line to be printed.
   If any of those conditions are not true, you should print an appropriate error message to the user and stop.  If they are all met, then you'll need to do a bit of arithmetic and use head and tail together to print out only the lines requested.

I know it's something along these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

heads -n 10 /etc/passwd | tails -3
```

Not sure how to go about the rest...

Comment: Perhaps the instructions are in your textbook?'

Comment: Do you know how to get the arguments? The commands are `head` and `tail`, not "heads" and "tails". I'd use `sed` for this, where you can specifically print a range of line numbers.

Comment: 'head -n $2 $3 | tail -n $1' this is what i have but its printing a little more than the 7-10 lines

Answer (score 1):

1. The number of attributes can be accessed through `$#`
2. `test -f $file` will test that a file exists and is a normal file
3. `test $x -lt $y` will test if $x is less than $y
4. `wc -l` will output the number of lines in a file

Comment: so how do I apply that?

Comment: It's very hard to help you there : instead of coming with a precise problem, you give a whole specification and seem to ask 'hey, can you do this for me?'. That would obviously be a loss of my time, and wouldn't teach you much. I've gave you pieces of knowledge you'll need to accomplish this exercise, stringing them with each other is the least you should learn to do by yourself.